# How to classify satellite image using backpropagation neural network

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I need to classify satellite image into 3 classes using back propagation neural network.

Can anyone help me to perform this in matlab?

How to train the neural network with multiple image and classify?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a generic (non-Matlab) answer.

Rasterize your input images into long vectors.

Create three output neurons, one for each class of images.

Proceed to train by associating each output neuron with an image.
For example, depending on the class, one output neuron should yield a "1"
and the others zero.

Depending on the complexity of the images, try 8-12 hidden neurons at first.

Comment: i didn't get you... could you please explain

Comment: Yes, examples would be great.